# Создать файл в папке %username%

Tags: python

Пытаюсь создать файл в папке %username%, но получаю ошибку:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '%username%\\text.txt'
```

Мой код:

```
import os

text = open(os.path.join("%username%", 'text.txt'), "w")
text.write("dfjkbnjkndskn")
```

Как правильно сделать поставленную задачу?

Comment: Используйте `pathlib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username` является переменой среды.
Вы можете получать доступ к переменным среды с помощью:

```
os.environ["varabile name"]
```

Вашу задачу можно решить, например, так:

```
import os

pathToFile = os.path.join("C:\\Users", os.environ["username"], "file.txt")
with open(pathToFile, "w") as file:
    file.write("File in user directory")
    print(pathToFile)
```

Или кроссплатформенно:

```
import os

pathToFile = os.path.join(os.environ["home"], "file.txt")
with open(pathToFile, "w") as file:
    file.write("File in user directory")
    print(pathToFile)
```

---

И ещё, `username` хранит имя пользователя, а не его директорию.

Даже, если бы можно было получить к ней доступ с помощью `%username%` - вы всё равно не сможете создать файл в директории содержащей только *имя пользователя* и *имя файла*.

Comment: os.path.expandvars() - как раз придумали для подобных случаев)